# How to get the length of a variable in bash?

Tags: bash

I currently have something of the form

```
abc=`find ~/$folder .. etc
```

I'd like to know how to get the number of items in abc:

```
abc_length = ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array:

```
abc=( $(find ...) )
abc_length=${#abc[@]}
```

Retrieve n-th result, say 10th:

```
echo ${abc[9]}
```

Or list all:

```
for dir_name in "${abc[@]}"; do
  echo $dir_name
done
```

---

Update: asker doesn't seem to want to process in script, so:

```
abc_length=$(find ... | wc -l)
```

You may want to reduce the number by 1 because the first result is `~/$folder`:

```
abc_length=$(( $(find ... | wc -l) - 1 ))
```

Comment: When trying to loop through abc, it will only list the first result!  abc=( $(find ~/$folder -name "$file@*" -type f) ), and the loop : for j in "$abc". Is there something wrong?

Comment: Don't forget the quotes: `for j in "${abc[@]}"`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by "items", so I will assume "directory entries". Assuming you have no files with newlines in their name, `echo "$abc" | wc -l` will do the trick.

If you want to count the number of characters, use `wc -c` instead.

Comment: The echo "$abc" | wc - l is working fine. But how to get that value to a variable?

Comment: just `abc_length=$(find ... | wc -l)` would do what you want.

Comment: I currently have: results=`find ~/$folder -name "$file@*" -type f`. How can I have a results_count that instead of calling again find, will only use the data that is already in the "results" variable? Thanks

Comment: You will always have to re-run `find` if you want an updated count.

Comment: `results=$(find ...); num_entries=$(echo "$results" | wc -l)`

Comment: @livibetter: That's not what the OP was asking. :-)

Comment: @Chris, I was kind of assuming OP only wants the count only, so I mis-read OP's comment.